# Windows-7 -tagged questions are highlighted light blue

Tags: discussion

Today I noticed several questions in the SU main feed were highlighted light blue. This afternoon I had a moment to compare them and found they were all the questions tagged Windows-7.

Is this behavior modifiable? For instance, can I select a different tag (or tags) and get those to be highlighted by default?

Is this behavior new?

Can I turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 4):

These questions are highlighted automatically due to the tags you've frequented.  There's no way to turn it off that I know of. Perhaps this should be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) unless I've just missed it.  This was put in a few months back IIRC.

You can manually add a tag to your favorites (and thus have it highlighted) by typing it into the "favorite tags" box on the right side of the home page. It's possible that you could remove Windows 7 from your favorites by adding it manually and then removing it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, yea I'm seeing I've been assigned the Windows-7 tag based on frequent visits. I think I'll submit a feature request that they add the ability in the tag preferences to remove auto-highlighting from specific tags, or the ability to turn off auto-highlighting.

Comment: @nhinkle Make it CW if you're going to use the word "I" to refer to yourself in my answer :P

Comment: @MatthewRead I was just adding some info. Making it CW is fine but it's not required. You're welcome to edit it again if that's not something you believe. I used "I" because it flows better. Sorry for stepping on your toes.