# why some question are highlighted?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows-7 -tagged questions are highlighted light blue](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3728/windows-7-tagged-questions-are-highlighted-light-blue)

As in the picture shown, **why some question are highlighted ?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because most likely you have some **favorite tags** which might include [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7)

Then all questions about [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) get highlighted on the site for you, because you're likely more interested in these

See this MSO question for more information: 
[What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

For future reference, [go have a look around the FAQ on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) it will most likely answer a lot of your questions

Comment: but I didn't have any favorite tag ! I saw it now !

Comment: Yeah, check the question @Sathya used to close this one as a duplicate